# Powershell function to perform regular expression checks

Tags: regex, powershell

I am writing a powershell function `(checkREGEX)` to perform regular expression checks on input data and return either **true** or **false**. The `RegEx`, The `inputData` to be checked and the `checkType` will all be coming from another function. The function will either perform one check or multiple checks. If multiples checks are to be preformed, the values to be checked will be separated by "**&&**" in the inputData.

The function is supposed to return **true** if the check type is set to *Match_Regex* and the RegEx has match the single entry in inputData (in case of a single check) or all the entries (in the case of multiple checks), or the check type is set to *Not_Match_Regex* and the RegEx has not matched the site entry (single check) or all the entries (multiple checks).

Conversely, the function is supposed to return **false** if the check type is set to *Match_Regex* and the RegEx hasn't matched the single entry or all the multiple entries, or the check type is set to *Not_Match_Regex* but the RegEx has matched the single entry or any of the multiple entries.

The function is not behaving as expected and I am trying to improve my code to make it be more accurate. I have commented the function to illustrate what I am trying achieve.

```
    function checkREGEX {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Compares the provided Inputdata against the provided Regex.

    .DESCRIPTION
    Takes in two values to compare. Runs Regex against Inputvalue, checks if there is a match and returns "true" or "false" depending on checkType. 

    .PARAMETER funcName
    (optional) function name that called this function. Used to display origin for debug prints.

    .PARAMETER regEx
     Set regex to be checked against Inputdata. 

    .PARAMETER inputData
    Value to be checked from valueData

    .PARAMETER checkType
    Type of check to perform

    .EXAMPLE
    checkREGEX -funcName "TestFunction" -regEx "^(Medium|Low|Minimal)[\s]*$" -inputData "Medium" -checkType "Match_Regex"
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([bool])]
    param(
        [String]$funcName, 
        [String]$regEx, 
        [String]$inputData,
        [ValidateSet('Match_Regex', 'Not_Match_Regex', '' )][String]$checkType
    )

    # Perform the RegEx check depending on the input type
    if ($inputData.Contains("&&")) {

        # Many checks need to be performed.
        if ($checkType -like 'Match_Regex' -or $checkType.Length -eq 0) {

            # All checks need to pass. When any one fails, no need to continue. the check has failed.
            $found = $true
            [array]$data = $inputData.Split("&&")
            foreach ($value in $data) {
                $RegExMatch = [regex]::match($value , $regEx)
                if ($RegExMatch.Success -like "False") {
                    $found = $false
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            # All checks need to fail. When any one passes, no need to continue. the check has passed.
            $found = $false
            [array]$data = $inputData.Split("&&")
            foreach ($value in $data) {
                $RegExMatch = [regex]::match($value , $regEx)
                if ($RegExMatch.Success -like "True") {
                    $found = $true
                    break
                }
            }

        }
    }
    else {
        # Only one check needs to be performed
        $found = $true
        $RegExMatch = [regex]::match($inputData , $regEx)
        if ($RegExMatch.Success -like "False") {
            $found = $false
            break
        }
    }

    #--- Return the result ---

    # The regEx should have matched but there was no match found. So, return fail.
    if (($checkType -like 'Match_Regex' -or $checkType.Length -eq 0) -and !$found) {
        Write-Verbose "[$funcName] Do Not match <$regEx> : <$inputData>"
        return $false
    }
    # The regEx shouldn't have matched but there was a match found. So, return fail.
    elseif (($checkType -like "Not_Match_Regex") -and $found) {
        Write-Verbose "[$funcName] Do Not match <$regEx> : <$inputData>"
        return $false
    }
    # The regEx matched when it was supposed to match or didn't matched when it wasn't supposed to. So, return pass.
    else {
        Write-Verbose "[$funcName] matched <$valueData> : <$inputData>"
        return $true
    }
}
```

The following returns **true**, witch is expected:

```
$inputData = "Medium"
$funcName = "TestFunction"
$regEx = "^(Medium|Low|Minimal)[\s]*$"
$checkType = "Match_Regex"

checkREGEX -funcName $funcName -regEx $regEx -inputData $inputData -checkType $checkType
```

The following returns nothing! weird... I should get a **false**.

```
$inputData = "Brown"
$funcName = "TestFunction"
$regEx = "^(Medium|Low|Minimal)[\s]*$"
$checkType = "Match_Regex"

checkREGEX -funcName $funcName -regEx $regEx -inputData $inputData -checkType $checkType
```

and the following returns **false** when it should be **true**.

```
$inputData = "Low&&Minimal"
$funcName = "TestFunction"
$regEx = "^(Medium|Low|Minimal)[\s]*$"
$checkType = "Match_Regex"

checkREGEX -funcName $funcName -regEx $regEx -inputData $inputData -checkType $checkType
```

I might be taking the wrong approach. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last test returns true on my side.

The issue with the second is a extra break in this section, try commenting it out.

```
else {
    # Only one check needs to be performed
    $found = $true
    $RegExMatch = [regex]::match($inputData , $regEx)
    if ($RegExMatch.Success -like "False") {
        $found = $false
        #break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the extra break resolved test #2. Also the issue with test #3 seem to be related to powershell core. I wrote and have been testing this in powershell core 7.1. When I test in the integrated powershell, it seem to be working as expected. Thanks for your help! Just another question. Is using [regex]::match() the best way to do this or can I improve it using a different method?

Comment: Regex::match() is fine. Just be aware that you've removed some options for using regex flags (case sensitivity, dotall etc). If I was nitpicking.. rather than strings delimited by && I would first have tried passing an array of strings for the check conditions. That way it's not confused by a regex string actually containing && and saves you checking single/multiple as two sections.